# fabric.js: Normalizing fabric.Polygon points after dragging/scaling/rotating

Tags: fabricjs, polygon

In fabric.js when a Polygon object is moved, scaled, or rotated via mouse cursor manipulation, the Polygon's original `points` array elements are not updated to reflect their new "true" current positions on the canvas.

This is problematic in my application, where we allow adding points to an existing polygon via clicks on the canvas, by taking the points array of the existing object, removing the existing object from the canvas, adding the new point to the points array, and creating a new polygon object with those points. This works fine if the polygon was not manipulated by the user.

Is there a way to, using the `object:modified` event, recreate the polygon updating its points to reflect their new true positions, taking into account the object's new position, scaling, and rotation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999034/how-does-transforming-points-with-a-transformmatrix-work-in-fabricjs Please check this answer and eventually upvote it. I will try to close this as duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does transforming points with a transformMatrix work in fabricJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999034/how-does-transforming-points-with-a-transformmatrix-work-in-fabricjs)

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi thanks, this does look very close to, if not exactly what I am looking for. I have not yet tried it in my application, but I've upvoted, and I think its safe to close this.