# Transforming location of Circles together with Polygon - FabricJs

Tags: fabricjs

I have a fabricjs polygon, with fabric js cirles on it's vertexes.
I am trying to move the circles upon modification of the polygon through drag, to do so I have tried to use what this post suggests: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999034/how-does-transforming-points-with-a-transformmatrix-work-in-fabricjs)

and made small changes (as I can't do canvas.clear(), because my canvas holds a background image):

Here is my code.

```
fabricPoly.on('modified', function () {

  const matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
  const transformedPoints = this.get('points')
    .map(function (p) {
      return new fabric.Point(p.x - fabricPoly.minX - fabricPoly.width / 2, p.y - fabricPoly.minY - fabricPoly.height / 2);
    })
    .map(function (p) {
      return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
    });

  const circles = transformedPoints.map(function (p, i) {
    const currCircleStyle = Object.assign({}, {
      radius: 10,
      fill: 'black',
      hasRotatingPoint: false,
      hasControls: false,
      selectable: true,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      hasBorders: false
    });
    currCircleStyle['index'] = i;
    currCircleStyle['left'] = p.x;
    currCircleStyle['top'] = p.y;
    return new fabric.Circle(currCircleStyle);
  });

  self.fabricList.slice(1).forEach(e => { // self.fabricList[0] is the polygon, and the rest are former circles
    this.canvas.remove(e);
  });
  circles.forEach((e, i) => {
    self.canvasRef.add(e);
  });

  this.points = transformedPoints;

  self.canvasRef.renderAll();
});
```

But, after the transformation is done, and the canvas.renderAll() is hit, the polygon seems to move further the it was dragged, in the same direction.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Which version are you using??

Comment: fabric js 1.7.22, canvas 1.6.9

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the circle objects using `canvas.getObjects('circle')` and remove all from canvas using `canvas.remove()`

for `V-1.x.x`

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {selection: false});
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([
  new fabric.Point(200, 50),
  new fabric.Point(250, 150),
  new fabric.Point(150, 150),
  new fabric.Point(350, 50),
],{fill:'yellow'});

polygon.on("modified", function () {
  var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
  var transformedPoints = this.get("points")
  .map(function(p){
    return new fabric.Point(p.x - polygon.minX -polygon.width/2, p.y - polygon.minY - polygon.height/2);
    })
  .map(function(p){
    return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
  });
  var circles = transformedPoints.map(function(p){
    return new fabric.Circle({
      left: p.x,
      top: p.y,
      radius: 3,
      fill: "red",
      originX: "center",
      originY: "center",
      hasControls: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      selectable: false
    });
  });
  
  this.canvas.remove(...this.canvas.getObjects('circle')).add.apply(this.canvas, circles).setActiveObject(this).renderAll();
});

canvas.add(polygon).renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<p>
Move, scale and rotate the polygon. The three red dots should match with the corners of the polygon after each modification.
</p>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

for `V-2.x.x`

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {selection: false});
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([
  new fabric.Point(200, 50),
  new fabric.Point(250, 150),
  new fabric.Point(150, 150),
  new fabric.Point(350, 50),
],{fill:'yellow'});

polygon.on("modified", function () {
  var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
  
  var transformedPoints = this.get("points")
  .map(function(p){
    var dimen = polygon._calcDimensions();
    return new fabric.Point(p.x - dimen.left -dimen.width/2, p.y - dimen.top - dimen.height/2);
    })
  .map(function(p){
    return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
  });
  var circles = transformedPoints.map(function(p){
    return new fabric.Circle({
      left: p.x,
      top: p.y,
      radius: 3,
      fill: "red",
      originX: "center",
      originY: "center",
      hasControls: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      selectable: false
    });
  });
  this.canvas.remove(...this.canvas.getObjects('circle')).add.apply(this.canvas, circles).setActiveObject(this).renderAll();
});

canvas.add(polygon).renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<p>
Move, scale and rotate the polygon. The three red dots should match with the corners of the polygon after each modification.
</p>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```